# mysqli will not insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a mysqli insert statement in php that will not insert at all. Neither will it give me any kind of error message from mysqli_error, it just fails. Here is the code.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
function addItems($name, $cost, $type){
$sql= "INSERT INTO `items`(`name`, `cost`, `type`) VALUES ('egg', 50, 'harvest')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
}
```

When I call the function it will create the sql variable just fine, but then it dies. I can select from this table just fine, but not insert. User that is being used has full permissions.

I found a few others that seemed to have the same issue, but their solutions did not work for me.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `$con` is out of the functions scope

Comment: I know that with integers it does not matter, but try putting quotes around 50 just in case.

Comment: @Dimitri that won't fix it.

Comment: Adding the global to $con worked. As soon as I can I will mark @hd's answer as the one that worked. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574632/steve) said, `$con` is out of the functions scope.

Two ways to fix this.

Use [**`global`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php);

```
function addItems($name, $cost, $type){
 global $con;
```

Inject the object

```
function addItems($name, $cost, $type, $con){
```

> Preference should be given to the second option (object injection). global is almost never a good idea
>
> ~ [@steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574632/steve) & the world.

Comment: Preference should be given to the second option. global is almost never a good idea

Comment: @Steve agreed! Will note that in the answer

Comment: @hd would I have to pass $con in when i call the function as well?

Comment: @DavidEllenburg yes,you would